Mapping Logitech mx master 2s buttons on zorin OS
i'm a newbie linux user and i'm having some trouble configurating my logitech mouse.
Yesterday I've installed zorin OS on my pc so i don't have great changes from a fresh zorin installation.
I'm trying to map the extra buttons of my mouse and i'm using logiops. I watched many tutorial, the wiki from the repo and other threads but i achived only the installation, I'm not able to set the buttons.
My logid.cfg file is:
    devices: (
    {
    name: "Wireless Mouse MX Master 2S ";
    smartshift:
    {
        on: true;
        threshold: 5; # 7 is ideal for work
    };

    dpi: 800;# <- you may change this number. 4000 is the maximum.

    buttons: (
        {
            cid: 0xc3;
            action =
            {
                type: "Gestures";
                gestures: (
                    {
                        direction: "Up";
                        mode: "OnRelease";
                        action =
                        {
                            type: "Keypress";
                            keys: ["KEY_LEFTCTRL", "KEY_C"];
                        };
                    },
                    {
                        direction: "Down";
                        mode: "OnRelease";
                        action =
                        {
                            type: "Keypress";
                            keys: ["KEY_LEFTCTRL", "KEY_LEFTALT", "KEY_DOWN"];
                        };
                    },
                    {
                        direction: "Left";
                        mode: "OnRelease";
                        action =
                        {
                            type: "Keypress";
                            keys: ["KEY_LEFTCTRL", "KEY_LEFTALT", "KEY_LEFT"];
                        };
                    },
                    {
                        direction: "Right";
                        mode: "OnRelease";
                        action =
                        {
                            type: "Keypress";
                            keys: ["KEY_LEFTCTRL", "KEY_LEFTALT", "KEY_RIGHT"];
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        direction: "None"
                        mode: "OnRelease";
                        action =
                        {
                            type: "Keypress";
                            keys: ["KEY_LEFTMETA"];
                        }
                    }
                );
            };
        },
        {
            cid: 0xc4;
            action =
            {
                type = "ToggleSmartshift";
            };
        }
    );
}
);

This file is from another thread, i only changed the up gesture on thumb button to see if something change
my goal is to set copy and paste on my left side buttons and back on thumb button. As you can see i tried to bind ctrl+c on up gesture but it doesn't work (i restarted logid with 'sudo systemctl restart logid').
If i run
sudo logid

my mouse is correctly detected on hidraw4 but seems not configurated:
config error
As u can see hidraw4 detect when my mouse went in sleep mode:
Sleep mode
I tried many configurations suggested by threads and repos wiki  but anything seems not to work.
I tried something like:
cid: 0xc3;
     action ={
          type: "Keypress";
          keys: ["KEY_LEFTCTRL", "KEY_C"];
}

now i don't remember what i did this morning :P
Can someone explain me where am i wrong and what should i do?
Thanks!
PS: i'm using the mouse from usb dongle and not from bluetooth

I heard that mapping Ctrl-C can be problematic; try a simple remap of a regular alphabet key to see if the Ctrl- combination is an issue.
